# Matching text from columns in Data Frame

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am looking to find keywords that appear within a search string (in this case, a research question). I think I'm close, but I'm not quite certain what the problem is I'm running in to. My data frame looks something like this:

```
Q1                                                     keywords
How do you assess strategic deterrence messaging?      Deterrence messaging effects perception assessment
An energy transition for green growth                  Energy transition sustainable
Some other research question here                      research keywords topics etc
```

where `Q1` refers to the question and the `keywords` are a list of words (in this case, cleaned-up Boolean searches with AND, NOT, and OR removed). What I'm trying to determine is whether any of the `keywords` appear in the `Q1` string, find the matches, and count how often that happens (so I can then say that `keywords` appeared in `column1` *n*% of the time, in `column2` *n*% of the time...).

Here's where I started, using `tidyverse`:

```
df_final <- df %>% 
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(
    Q1,
    str_c(df$keywords, collapse = "|") %>% regex(ignore_case = T)),
    match = map_chr(matches, str_c, collapse = ", "),
    count = map_int(matches, length)
  )
```

But I'm not getting any matches. I'm assuming it might have something to do with my `keyword` column? Does this need to be converted into, say, a vector or comma-separated list for this to work right? Thanks ahead of time for suggestions!

EDIT: A sample output from `dput()`:

```
structure(list(Q1 = c("Assessing the effects of strategic deterrence messaging in the cognitive dimension", 
"How do you assess effects of strategic deterrence messaging?", 
"Determine Strategic Implications of Climate Change to USG/DoD"
), keywords = c("Deterrence messaging effects perception assessment", 
"political philosophy sociology social sciences history marketing power structure government governing class bourgeoisie social class military class ruling class governing class", 
"Climate Change Strategic Global Warming Strategic Climate Change Policy Global Warming Policy"
)), .Names = c("Q1", "keywords"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you add a quick `df` example with `dput()`

Comment: Done -- added an edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will return your data.frame plus a count of occurrences of the keywords in the question based on the keywords after the question. In your sample output that is 3 0 6. All functions are from  the `tidyverse` packages.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df  %>%  mutate(count = map2_int(Q1, keywords, function(x, y) sum(str_detect(str_to_lower(x), str_to_lower(flatten_chr(str_split(y, " ")))))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Q1                                                                                 keywords                                        count
  <chr>                                                                              <chr>                                           <int>
1 Assessing the effects of strategic deterrence messaging in the cognitive dimension Deterrence messaging effects perception assess~     3
2 How do you assess effects of strategic deterrence messaging?                       political philosophy sociology social sciences~     0
3 Determine Strategic Implications of Climate Change to USG/DoD                      Climate Change Strategic Global Warming Strate~     6
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Q1 = c("Assessing the effects of strategic deterrence messaging in the cognitive dimension", 
"How do you assess effects of strategic deterrence messaging?", 
"Determine Strategic Implications of Climate Change to USG/DoD"
), keywords = c("Deterrence messaging effects perception assessment", 
"political philosophy sociology social sciences history marketing power structure government governing class bourgeoisie social class military class ruling class governing class", 
"Climate Change Strategic Global Warming Strategic Climate Change Policy Global Warming Policy"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm getting an error when I apply this to the whole dataset -- is this a problem with special characters appearing in the text, maybe? 

    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
    Evaluation error: Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX).
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  empty search patterns are not supported
    2: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  empty search patterns are not supported

Comment: In the keywords list you have, are there any records that have more than 1 space between the keywords? Special chars shouldn't be an issue. But if you can narrow it down to an example, I can see if there is a solution.

Comment: I think I took multiple spaces out, but I can double check. There are also some cases where there aren't any keywords, would that throw the error? EDIT: To be clear, I haven't replaced these empty keywords with `NA`, etc. But if that is causing the error, the easiest thing might just be to throw out those rows.

Comment: Okay, it's been solved. There must've been special characters or something present in the strings. Using `df$keywords <- str_replace_all(df$keywords, "[[:punct:]]", "")` seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be optimal but maybe it helps. I added `tolower()` as I assume you don't care if deterrence or Deterrence.

```
a <-tolower(unique(unlist(strsplit(df$keywords, " "))))

dfcounter <- data.frame(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(df$Q1, " ")))),stringsAsFactors = F)

dfcounter[match(a,dfcounter$Var1,nomatch = 0),]
```